# Manipulating function sample sizes in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, covariance, vba

Suppose I had two time series consisting of weekly data points, and I want to compute the covariance of the time series for the last n weeks using the covariance function in Excel.

Would it be possible to set this scenario up in such a way that a certain cell contains the number of weeks of data I want to compute the covariance for?

That is, changing the cell element to k would lead to the already computed covariance for n weeks to change to the covariance of the data series for the last k weeks?

Comment: I would set the data so that "fresh" data is added at the bottom, then set the functions to use the last n rows for the calculations ;: starting with the last valid number and working back n to find the beginning. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You decided that sample data was not important so here is some.

```
 date          nmbr
03-30-2017      4
04-04-2017      4
04-07-2017      2
04-09-2017      2
04-12-2017      1
04-15-2017      4
04-18-2017      1
04-21-2017      2
04-24-2017      1
04-26-2017      3
04-30-2017      4
05-02-2017      5
05-07-2017      4
05-09-2017      2
05-10-2017      1
05-12-2017      5
05-14-2017      4
```

My crystal ball tells me that this question is not so much about Excel's COVARIANCE.P or COVARIANCE.S but about limiting date related data. To this end, I'll simply SUM 4 weeks of data.

The formulas needed in E2:H2 (see supplied image) are:

```
=TODAY()
4
=FLOOR(E2-(F2*7), 7)+1
=SUM(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(G2, A:A)+ISNA(MATCH(G2, A:A, 0))):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)))
```

[image]

Note that the dates are in ascending order.

Comment: I understand from OP that there are two columns of data (say columns B and C) apart the dates, and the goal is to calculate the covariance of last k samples in the data. I had prepared an answer for that but I am too lazy to provide such a (nice) tutorial. So I suggest that you include that possibility in the answer :). Hint: `=COVAR(OFFSET(A1, 1+COUNT(A:A)-G2,,G2),OFFSET(B1, 1+COUNT(A:A)-G2,,G2) )` where the number k could be entered in `G2`.

Comment: Personally, I try to use the non-volatile INDEX instead of OFFSET but I think you should post your answer. There aren't many Q's or A's worth an upvote today.

Comment: @Jeeped no it wouldn't add much to your answer, the essence of the difficulty is actually answered. OP can adjust it to their need using the technique. BTW, it's sunday... ;)